# Another router profile - which bit to use?

Tags: router, router-bit

The photo is a square slice through a 6 x 6 post which has this shaping done each corner. I am replacing the post and want to reproduce this. I need a bit because the routed part of the edge is about 10 foot long.

[image: Existing edge]

I've been hitting  the local stores etc, and the nearest we can find is a beading bit - but those have square flats and a basic bead/roundover - where as mine seems to be two coves with a 90 degree bead. I've also checked the entire range of Diablo profiles online.

I can't believe this was a custom bit, as it was done in the backyard by the people who erected the arbor as part of landscaping the yard - and I doubt they shelled out for that.

If I can get the "class" of bit (e.g. bead, roundover) defined, I can then work out the size I need.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that is was 1 or more molding planes.

Comment: Similar to (same as?) the last time we had a similar query, this could be done with creative use of multiple bits and multiple passes. And the original could have been done this way. *"I can't believe this was a custom bit... I doubt they shelled out for that."* But maybe it IS a custom bit, but they used it enough (e.g. this profile was one of their USPs) that the cost did make economic sense. I have no idea what the price range was for custom router bits back in the day, but I bet it was more reasonable than one might expect, particularly for solid HSS which is viable for work in softwoods.

Comment: Sorry didn't have room to include this, the custom bit could easily have been for a spindle moulder rather than any size of hand-held router. The need for custom spindle-moulder knives was apparently so commonplace that manufacturers all offered custom-profile services.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also coming to the conclusion that this was multiple bits. It was done 20 years ago. But the wood that was shaped is a 6x6 x 16ft beam, and I can't see that being loaded onto a jobsite router table (for example). I can see two 1/4" coves to get the shoulders, leaving an interior 90 degree corner that would be rounded over. But I've never used a router so am not sure if that's practical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Y’all are going to plotz when I tell you this.

Roman ogee. Twice.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Rotating images from router sellers and overlaying profile looks like match. I thought roller bearing would prevent second cut but bearing surface unaffected by first cut. Maybe good idea to saw of corner at start to reduce load on bit.

Comment: Thank you ... my son suggested the same thing but we didn't have an ogee bit to try. He uses routers, I'm hand tools (because, yeah, I'm old enough that's how I was taught).

I went down to HF last night for a cheap set of bits to experiment with

Comment: @kdopen, you may be aware of this already but in case not, there is a wide variety in ogee bits. Not just in size and shaft diameter, but also in how 'long' the ogee is so if you need a dead-on match you'll have to buy with care.

Comment: Meant to say yesterday, +100 innernets points for drawing skilz :-D

Comment: +1 for the proper use of "plotz". The rest of the answer is just bonus material! :D

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's an ogee of some type combined with a cove as I can't reproduce it with just a roman ogee. The middle bead ends up as a sharp 90 degree vertex

Comment: Think we got there - the trick was to fit a larger OD bearing. Thanks all